# QGIS Connection with MSSQL localdb not possible correctly

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I installed MSSql Server Express with localDB. Everything looks ok. The connection with the LocalDB is nessesary and the tables and views are displayed in the QGIS MSSQL Dioalog. A primary key is defiened! See here:

[image]

... the Connection Dialog worked fine

[image]

... the QGIS MSSQL Table Dialog

The features are not displayed, and the attributetable is displayed as empty
The attribute table is always empty, if I connect a table with no geometry

Some notes and questions:

Using QGIS 2.10.1

MS SQL Server Express localdb with SP2

DSN Connection String for localDB with:"DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Integrated Security=True;"

Is something wrong with the Connection String?
It is not possible to connect with the Native Client?
Is somethin wrong with the tabledeffinition?
Why the column primary key in the QGIS Dialog is empty?

...or it is not necessary to connect to a localDb